# Limit a CSS selector to the nearest parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I have this DOM structure

```
<div class="a b">
  <div class="c" id="c1">
    <div class="a">
      <div class="c" id="c2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to create a selector like

.a.b .c { ...}

And have it only apply to id=c1 and not id=c2 because the "a" element c2 is inside of doesn't have "b" too.

But currently c2 is also inside a much higher parent that has "a" and "b" so the selector applies.

Note that there could be more parents in the chain between "a" and "c".
I could do this in Javascript/jquery but I'd like a pure CSS solution.

Comment: More about selectors, with examples: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 4):

You can use child combinator selector [`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to target the child elements with a specific parent element - see a demo below where the `#c1` is targeted with a red color & a pseudo element.

Now you can have the *selector* (see how a pseudo applies only to `#c1`), but the parent styles will be inherited. So you would have to reset the styles. (`color: initial` in the demo below)

```css
.a.b .c {
  color: initial;
}
.a.b > .c {
  color: red;
}
.a.b > .c:before {
  content: '1. ';
}
```

```html
<div class="a b">
  <div class="c" id="c1">one
    <div class="a">
      <div class="c" id="c2">two
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```